# ImportError: DLL load failed : The specified module could not be found

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

[image]

I am trying to run the code.

While running the code i got the error as

> ImportError: DLL load failed : The specified module could not be found.

which was mentioned in the image but i installed `pyscopg2` in my device.
I am using python 2.7, pandas ,numpy, pyscopg2.
could you help me how to sort this issue.

Comment: Please add whatever information you think it is relevant from the image as text. Attaching text images is not a good practice here, I think.

Comment: Please check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask so that you can improve the chances of getting an answer that will solve your problem.

Comment: Please click on the "enter image description" you will get more information.

Comment: Please post your code as text, not an image.